# split multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, split

I created a multidimensional array in python. It is an array of arrays with size (100,91).

I need to create a list of subarrays, with pre-specified length.

I need to code it in a flexible way. The size of the array of array changes every time.

My code looks like the following:

```
N=100
i=np.random.poisson(10,N)
v=np.random.uniform(0,200,sum(i))
r= np.vstack([v]*91).T
splitted_r=np.split(r,list(i),axis=1)
```

I was expecting of creating subarrays each of them with a number of rows indicated in i. How can I do it in the fastest possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to split your array into `n` subarrays, where the `length` of each subarray (i.e. the number of elements in the first dimension) depends on the respective number generated by the poisson distribution.

You can obtain the inhomogeneous splits by using `np.cumsum()` to identify the indices of each split, and subsequently using a list comprehension to perform the splitting. The code below shows how this can be done, where I lowered `N` to 3 in order for obtaining results in the `print` statements that can be included as comments in the code to show how it works.

```
from copy import deepcopy

import numpy as np

# code from OP
N = 3
i = np.random.poisson(10,N)
print(i)  # [9 5 7]

# based on generated lengths of subarrays, identify the respective indices using
# `np.cumsum()`; to identify the starting indices, a second cumsum list is created
# and all values are shifted to the right, adding 0 at the beginning
cumsum = np.cumsum(i).tolist()
cumsum_shifted = deepcopy(cumsum)
cumsum_shifted.insert(0, 0)
cumsum_shifted = cumsum_shifted[:-1]
print(cumsum)  # [9, 14, 21]
print(cumsum_shifted)  # [0, 9, 14]

# code from OP
v = np.random.uniform(0,200,sum(i))
r = np.vstack([v]*91).T

# split array into subarrays
splitted_r = np.asarray(
    [r[i_css:i_cs] for i_css, i_cs in zip(cumsum_shifted, cumsum)],
    dtype=object
)
print(f"Shapes of subarrays: {[r.shape for r in splitted_r]}")
# Shapes of subarrays: [(9, 91), (5, 91), (7, 91)]
```